# How much does an anime cost per minute of animation especially with the use of cell-shaded CGI?

Tags: anime-production

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p18CbMcG-es

What's the cost per minute of an animation using cell-shaded CGI?

I heard the cost for Avatar-level CGI could be from $100,000 to $1,000,000 per minute, so I was wondering about cell-shaded CGI, and what about triple AAA game quality CGI like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ofWtkPs92Nc?

I thought that for cell-shaded CGI the cost wouldn't exceed 10,000$ per minute, but I am wondering if it would include the voice actor and sounds. Since the rate seem to vary depending on what technology is used and what are inside the scenes how much do you think the two videos above would cost per minute? Is there any statistics available that would give people an idea of how much it might cost? Does the cost include the audio?

Comment: While the overall question is acceptable, re: "how much do you think the two videos above would cost per minute", take note that Stack Exchange Q&A sites focus on factual info, not personal opinion/speculation, unless backed up with strong evidence.